# Test annotation code is not working, just BeforeMethod is working

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

My code is working until @BeforeMethod and it is opening the URL, but what I'm typing after @Test is not working. It is not typing credentials on the login page, hence Test failed.

```
package com.test;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
// import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Great {
WebDriver driver;

@BeforeMethod
public void setup()
    {

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Program Files 
(x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chromedriver.exe");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
String baseurl = "https://getfieldforce.com/dishqa"; 
driver.get(baseurl);
// Actions act = new Actions(driver);
        }   

@Test (priority=0)
public  void login()
{
     System.out.println("Login process starts");
     driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("123@p.com");
     driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("123456");
     driver.findElement(By.id("cta")).click();
     System.out.println("Login Sucessfully");
    }
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting and on which line number you are getting that error

Answer (score 0):

Removing webdriver from this line fixed the issue;  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

Thanks for looking into this :-)